# Different validation rules on select option changes [Yii]

Tags: php, ajax, yii, validation

I have the following situation: I want to validate through AJAX a form. The first field of this form is a select element with two options. The validation rules changes when the user changes the select element value. I've added the following function in my controller:

```
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='inquilini-form')
    {
                    $model->scenario = $_POST['Inquilini']['tipo'];
                    //$model->save();
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}
```

the model is `Inquilini` and the select element is `tipo`, I simply change the scenario when the value changes, but then no AJAX validation is applied! No CSS `error` or `success` classes were added!

Can someone help me please?

Comment: what you have tried should work, you might have other errors, do you have different validations for the changed scenario in your model?

Comment: I have different rules in overrides of `rules()` function with `'on'=>'scenario'` clauses..

Comment: then it should work, because i just tried it, if you are not sure about your rules, then can you put that code up?

Comment: here it is http://pastebin.com/TAZXDVxJ

Comment: even rules look good, sorry, i can't think of any other error that could be causing this

Comment: did u already take a look at the ajax response and the header data sent with the ajax request?

Comment: yes take a look at the ajax response, to know where the error could be

Comment: Also, please note that Yii will only add validation errors / success - classes to those inputs which were already changed. AFAIK all fields are validated at each Ajax-Request but only the relevant ones (those who have been focused and changed) will receive the corresponding validation class (success, error)

Comment: have you auto-generated your form? if not, please show your form's code. i had answered another question related to error css being applied, and that led me to think that this could be due to some mistake in your form, so let me see your form's code.

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess that you need to do following in your `Form` `'enableAjaxValidation'=>true` 
for further details please see [How to use AJAX form validation](http://learnyii.blogspot.com/2010/12/yii.html)